# Replacing chars with padded index

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I Have a string with special chars and i have to replace those chars with an index (padded n '0' left).

Fast example for better explanation:

I have the string "0980 0099 8383 $$$$" and an index (integer) 3
result should be "0980 0099 8383 0003"

The special characters are not necessarily in sequence.
the source string could be empty or it may not contain any special characters

I've already written functions that works.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceCounter(this string source, int counter, string character)
    {
        string res = source;

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(character))
            {
                if (res.Contains(character))
                {
                    // Get ALL Indexes position of character
                    var Indexes = GetIndexes(res, character);

                    int max = GetMaxValue(Indexes.Count);

                    while (counter >= max) 
                    { 
                        counter -= max; 
                    }

                    var new_value = counter.ToString().PadLeft(Indexes.Count, '0');

                    for (int i = 0; i < Indexes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        res = res.Remove(Indexes[i], 1).Insert(Indexes[i], new_value[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            res = source;
        }

        return res;
    }

    private static List<int> GetIndexes(string mainString, string toFind)
    {
        var Indexes = new List<int>();

        for (int i = mainString.IndexOf(toFind); i > -1; i = mainString.IndexOf(toFind, i + 1))
        {
            // for loop end when i=-1 (line.counter not found)
            Indexes.Add(i);
        }

        return Indexes;
    }

    private static int GetMaxValue(int numIndexes)
    {
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numIndexes; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                max = 9;
            else
                max = max * 10 + 9;
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

but i don't really like it (first of all because i'm passing the char as string.. and not as a char).

```
string source = "000081059671####=1811";
int index = 5;
string character = "#";

string result = source.ReplaceCounter(index, character);
```

can it be more optimized and compact?
Can some good soul help me?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The index is variable so:

If the index is 15

```
string source = "000081059671####=1811";
int index = 15;
string character = "#";

string result = source.ReplaceCounter(index, character);
// result = "0000810596710015=1811"
```

it should be a check if the index > max number
in my code i posted above, if this case happened i remove from index the "max" value until index < max number

What is mux number? if the special chars number is 4 (as in the example below) the max number will be 9999

```
string source = "000081059671####=1811";
// max number 9999
```

Comment: What is expected output if `source= "0000##81#059671####=1811";`

Comment: 0000008100596710005=1811

Comment: You can use a Regex.Replace to perform the replacement in a single line without generating temporary strings

Comment: And now I thought of an even simpler solution and faster - StringBuilder and a single reverse iteration to replace characters in place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yet another edit**

From a comment it seems that more than one digit can be used. In this case the `counter` can be converted to a `string` and treated as a `char[]` to pick the character to use in each iteration :

```
public static string ReplaceCounter(this string source, 
                                    int counter, 
                                    char character) 
{
    var sb=new StringBuilder(source);
    var replacements=counter.ToString();
    int r=replacements.Length-1;
    for(int i=sb.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(sb[i]==character)
        {
            sb[i]=r>=0 ? replacements[r--] : '0';
            
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This can be used for any number of digits.`"0980 0099 8383 $$$$".ReplaceCounter(15,'$')` produces `0980 0099 8383 0015`

**An edit**

After posting the original answer I remembered one can modify a string without allocations by using a `StringBuilder`. In this case, the last match needs to be replaced with one character, all other matches with another. This ca be a simple reverse iteration :

```
public static string ReplaceCounter(this string source, 
                                    int counter, 
                                    char character) 
{
    var sb=new StringBuilder(source);
    bool useChar=true;
    for(int i=sb.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(sb[i]==character)
        {
            sb[i]=useChar?(char)('0'+counter):'0';
            useChar=false;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine("0000##81#059671####=1811".ReplaceCounter(5,'#'));
Console.WriteLine("0980 0099 8383 $$$$".ReplaceCounter(3,'$'));
------
0000008100596710005=1811
0980 0099 8383 0003
```

**Original Answer**

Any string modification operation produces a new temporary string that need to be garbage collected. This adds up so quickly that avoiding temporary strings can result in >10x speed improvements when processing lots of text or lots of requests. That's better than using parallel processing.

You can use [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_) to perform complex replacements *without* allocating temporary strings. You can use one of the  [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_) overloads that use a `MatchEvaluator` to produce dynamic output, not just a single value.

In this case :

```
var source = "0000##81#059671####=1811";

var result = Regex.Replace(source,"#", m=>m.NextMatch().Success?"0":"5");

Console.WriteLine(result);
--------
0000008100596710005=1811
```

[Match.NextMatch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch?view=net-5.0) returns the next match in the source, so `m.NextMatch().Success` can be used to identify the last match and replace it with the `index`.

This would fail if the character was one of the Regex pattern characters. This can be avoided by escaping the character with [Regex.Escape(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0)

This can be packed in an extension method

```
public static string ReplaceCounter(this string source, 
                                    int counter,
                                    string character) 
{
    return Regex.Replace(source,
               Regex.Escape(character), 
               m=>m.NextMatch().Success?"0":counter.ToString());
}

public static string ReplaceCounter(this string source, 
                                    int counter, 
                                    char character) 
    =>ReplaceCounter(source,counter,character.ToString());
```

This code

```
var source= "0980 0099 8383 $$$$";
var result=source.ReplaceCounter(5,"$");
```

Returns

```
0980 0099 8383 0003
```

Comment: That's a really complete and nice answer.
but is not working prerfectly.
if my index > 9 the returned string is wrong in both cases.
that's my fault, I have not specified the maximum value of the index because I do not know it. there should be the check: 2 special characters -> maximum index 99

Comment: @DavidePavani what is the correct string in this case? This answer works based on the question's description and samples. `99` is two characters, not one, so the StringBuilder can't work. The regex *can* though, provided you explain what is actually needed. Instead of `'0'+counter`, you can use `counter.ToString()`

Comment: In the original answer:
if i'm passing 15 as index the answer is 0980 0099 8383 00015
but I expect it to be 0980 0099 8383 0015

regex is replacing "####" with "00015" but i dont want to modify the source string lenght

Comment: @DavidePavani you're passing 3 not 15. With that example you *can* use the StringBuilder

Comment: is an example, the index is variable

Comment: @DavidePavani edit the question and explain what you actually want then. What you ask now *can* be done with a StringBuilder, with a slightly different conditions -`99` is two characters. So you need a `string` or `char[]`. You can use an index to pick characters for replacement instead of a single char

Comment: @DavidePavani I edited the method to handle multi-digit `counters`. Edit the question to make it clear what you expect as input and output, otherwise the answers make little sense. How do you feel when a manager tells you to throw away what you did because they really wanted something different from what they asked?

Comment: Edited the answer. i'm so sorry for the bad question. let me know if is not clear

Comment: The last method you posted it works really good.
Is the best answer.
thanks a lot!! and thanks for the patient.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest such solutiuon (got rid out of helper methods:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceCounter(this string source, int counter, char character)
    {
        string res = source;
        string strCounter = counter.ToString();
        bool counterTooLong = false;
        int idx;
        // Going from the and backwards, we fill with counter digits.
        for(int i = strCounter.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            idx = res.LastIndexOf(character);
            // if we run out of special characters, break the loop.
            if (idx == -1)
            {
                counterTooLong = true;
                break;
            }

            res = res.Remove(idx, 1).Insert(idx, strCounter[i].ToString());
        }
        // If we could not fit the counter, we simply throw exception
        if (counterTooLong) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        // If we did not fill all placeholders, we fill it with zeros.
        while (-1 != (idx = res.IndexOf(character))) res = res.Remove(idx, 1).Insert(idx, "0");

        return res;
    }
}
```

[Here's fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YOruW6)

Comment: It would be really nice if you provide fiddle for your solution

Comment: Thats nice. it works perfectly and it is much more compact.
I just edited the return value in case of (counterTooLong == true) because i dont want to throw an exception, but simply return back the source string without any edit.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Added fiddle :)